# How to run method present in a file from the main method present in another file with mingw

Tags: c, netbeans, mingw

I have installed mingw on netbeans for C programming.
Then I have created a file "Myfile.c", in which I created a method `callme()`.
But this file is not containing main method.
I want to call `callme()` from another file containing main method.

**Myfile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void callme() {
    printf("I am called");
}
```

**EntryFile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // How to call callme() from here OR use this method anyhow.
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

For some reasons I don't want to create main method in `Myfile.c`.

**Edited**

**Myfile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void callme();
void callme() {
    printf("I am called");
}
```

**EntryFile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    callme();
}
```

**Error**

```
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Afzalex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStoreRoom'
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppstoreroom.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Afzalex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStoreRoom'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Myfile.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Myfile.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Myfile.o Myfile.c
make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target `newmain.cpp', needed by `build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o'.  Stop.
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Afzalex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStoreRoom'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Afzalex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStoreRoom'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: What are you trying and what errors does it produce? Copy&Paste of your commands and the output would help us immensly =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614269/function-prototype-declarations

Comment: I don't know how to call `callme()` present in `Myfile.c` from `EntryFile.c`. I want to know how to call it. It is not yet giving error, I have not done anything still that it will show error to me. And I cant copy the code, I will be making 1000 lines of code in many files and don't want to keep all code in one file. @AndreasGrapentin

Comment: in that case, read the question that @2501 linked. the keyword you are looking for is `header file`

Comment: Do you mean creating prototype will resolve my problem? @AndreasGrapentin

Comment: yes. prototypes are a way of telling the compiler what functions will be available from other parts of the program.

Comment: Still not working... @AndreasGrapentin

Comment: @afzalex that is because you put the prototype in the wrong file =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67239/discussion-between-afzalex-and-andreas-grapentin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @LPs has pointed out in his answer, you should probably create a file `MyFile.h` with the contents

```
/* include guards (research the term if you don't know it) */
#ifndef MYFILE_H 
#define MYFILE_H

void callme(void);

#endif // MYFILE_H
```

and include this file from your `EntryFile.c` using

```
#include "MyFile.h"
```

alternatively, you could write the prototype directly into `EntryFile.c` using

```
extern void callme(void);
```

at global scope before using the function. Both ways will make the function known to the compiler, and you can use it inside your `main` function.

Answer (score 4):

Create a MyFile.h where you'll write:

```
extern void callme();
```

Then add in EntryFile.c

```
#include "MyFile.h"
```

Then you can call callme in your main method

Comment: note that the `extern` keyword is optional here. =)

Comment: Yes, but I use to put always extern in .h just to be sure to avoid linker problems.